# How do I get the Commerce order type programmatically?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have two Commerce **order types**, *order_a* and *order_b*, which I created at `/admin/commerce/config/order-types`.

I'm using Commerce 2 on Drupal 8.

I want to process them differently in **hook_commerce_order_presave()**.

How can I programmatically get the order type?  When I check the entity type, it only has `commerce_order`, but I want to know what type of commerce order it is.  I can't find a method to get the order type specifically.

Here's the code I am using:

```
function MYMODULE_commerce_order_presave(\Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->isNew()) {
    kint($entity->getEntityTypeId());
    die();
```

Comment: Assuming the type is the bundle (probably is): `$entity->bundle()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order type is the bundle so you can use [`EntityInterface::bundle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Abundle/8.4.x) to get that info:

```
$type = $entity->bundle();
```